# Quick JavaScript to find URLs on the page and make them into links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to replace plain URLs with links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links)

So I've got a page with a bunch of URLs and no links. The page is constantly pulling in new information, so I can't add the tags myself. Where could I find a fast, lightweight, JavaScript  snippet or jQuery plugin to linkify these URLs?

Turn `http://blahblah.com/`

into `<a href="http://blahblah.com/">http://blahblah.com/</a>`

Comment: I can foresee some regex coming.

Comment: Those functions in the solutions require the input of specific text, I need to be able to specify an element and have all of its contained text be changed.

Comment: Just pass the data received from the ajax to it before appending the linkified version? Or grab the element's html with `.html()` and replace it with the linkified version..

Comment: THis yields no dice: `replaceURLWithHTMLLinks($('li').text())` (regarding the first solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links)

Comment: `$('li').html(replaceURLWithHTMLLinks($('li').html()))` or, if you have more than one `li`, `$('li').each(function() { $(this).html(replaceURLWithHTMLLinks($(this).html())); });`

Comment: Regexps are brittle and should be avoided. I've summarized [the best autolinkification libraries in another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21925491/1269037).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JQuery:
Assuming your links are in p (for performance, use the closest selector)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('p').each(function(){
        var content = $(this).html();
        content = content.replace(/[^"=](http:\/\/\S*)/ig, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');
        $(this).html(content);
    });
});​
```

Surely not the most optimized way, and the regex is not really well-formed but at least it doesn't replaces URLs that are in tags attributes (like images src).

Comment: Regexps are brittle and should be avoided. I've summarized [the best autolinkification libraries in another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21925491/1269037).